# Perform Consecutive 'diff' Operation on Files using Python

Tags: python, diff

Consider I have a scenario like this :

[image]

My ultimate objective is to do the following (in_words if image is not clear):

1) Run linux "diff" command between Master_File and Slave_1 File, save it as Diff_1

2) Run linux "diff" command between Master_File and Slave_2 File, save it as Diff_2

3) Run linux "diff" command between Master_File and Slave_3 File, save it as Diff_3

4) Run linux "diff" command between diff_1 and diff_2 File, save it as Semi-Final-Diff

5) Run linux "diff" command between Semi-Final-Diff and diff_3 File and save it as Final_Diff

I tried to achieve this by using 'reduce' from functools, but facing issues.

Let's say I have created all the initial diff's...

```
from functools import reduce

total_diffs =  ['1','2','3']

def diff_major(a,b):
    out = run_os_command('diff -s '+str(a)+'_'+str(b)+' >diff_'+str(a)+str(b)+'.log')           

def diff_to_diff(total_diffs):
    d = []
    for i in total_diffs:
        d.append('diff_'+str(i)+'.log')
    print d
    reduce(diff_major, d)
```

I get the output:

```
['diff_1.log', 'diff_2.log', 'diff_3.log']
Diffing diff_1.log and diff_2.log
Diffing None and diff_3.log
```

Why does it blow-off at second diff and changes the name to NONE? Also, how can I achieve this?

Comment: In `diff_to_diff`, where is `a` defined?

Comment: oops. a should have been i in diff_to_diff.my mistake

Answer (score 1):

`diff_major` returns `None` as it has no `return` statement.

`reduce` works by taking the first 2 items in the supplied iterable, in this instance `1` and `2`, and providing them as inputs to the supplied function with 2 parameters. It uses the return from this function as the first input to the next iteration; it then takes the next item in the iterable, in this case `3`, and provides that as the second input. This repeats until the iterable is exhausted, at which point it returns the final returned value from the supplied function.